# apollo client rest gql pass variable /todo/2

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I'm trying to use react apollo client 2.64 with a restful backend.

localhost:/api/todos    returns all items
localhost:/api/todos/1  returns a single item.

I'm having difficulty passing the parameter into the path... resolved it like this but I know this isn't the correct way:

```
//passing as a function to add parameter instead of the gql directly
export const GET_TODO = (id) => gql`
query {
  todo  @rest(type: "Todo", path: "todo/${id}") {
    id
    subject
    body
    status
    result
  }
}
`;

.... 
//consuming in component: 
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_TODO(3))
```

1. how can I pass a parameter correctly?
2. how do I control the caching? as I select a single todo from the multiple section, it should update from the backend, then potential children should be using the cached results again.

Thank you in advance!